# How to pass python arguments to perl script?

Tags: python

I am writing a python script, from I am trying to call perl script. The input to the perl scripts are python arguments.

```
 row[i[k]]=re.sub(r"^_", "", row[i[k]])
 row[i[k]]=re.sub(r"{", "[", row[i[k]])
 row[i[k]]=re.sub(r"}", "]", row[i[k]])
 row[i[0]]=re.sub(r"^_", "", row[i[0]])
 row[i[0]]=re.sub(r"{", "[", row[i[0]])
 row[i[0]]=re.sub(r"}", "]", row[i[0]])
 cmd = "perl process_str.pl -str1 "row[i[0]]" -str2 "row[i[k]]""
 os.system(cmd)
```

But I'm seeing following error on running the python script:

```
cmd = "perl process_str.pl -str1 "row[i[0]]" -str2 "row[i[k]]""
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Put simple quote instead of double for the inner quotes `cmd = "perl process_str.pl -str1 'row[i[0]]' -str2 'row[i[k]]'"`

Comment: Removed Perl tag as nothing about this question is specific to Perl. You are building a shell command

Comment: And don't do what azro suggests. 1) That's would not interpolate the values but pass the expressions as-is, and 2) If it did interpolate, it would suffer from a [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) bug

Answer (score 2):

The following can be used:

```py
subprocess.call([ "perl", "process_str.pl", "-str1", row[i[0]], "-str2", row[i[k]] ])
```

There's no point invoking a shell to launch `perl` when we can launch `perl` directly. And since we avoid using a shell, we avoid having to build a shell command.

Comment: Output? You mean what the program prints to stdout? You want to print to stdout what the program prints to stdout? Well, hmmm, that already happens.

Comment: the output of perl script is string and when i run pythin it is not giving any outputs

Comment: No. If it's not outputting anything, it's not outputting anything.

Comment: I have run perl script independently and it has worked properly for me. Then when i include the perl script in python it is nt working.

Comment: perl process_str.pl -str1 "iod.BP_0_D[104,44,32,20,8,105,45,33,21,9]" -str2 "MCA_DQS_H[9]_RSVD),(MCA_DQS_H[8:5]_MCA_DM[3:0]),MCA_DQS_H[4:0]"
BP_0_D[104] , MCA_DQS_H_9_RSVD_
BP_0_D[44] , MCA_DQS_H_8_MCA_DM_3

Comment: Then you use used a different environment, or a different command. I have no idea what you changed.